# Is Raspberry Pi 3 B+ power supplier compatible also with Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, pi-3b+, power-supply

It seems that my Raspberry Pi 2 power supplier stopped working (the power led switchs on and off periodically).
Due to this I was wondering if my current Pi 3 B+ power supplier can be used also with the old Pi 2, because their voltage is slightly different.

Here are more details about both power suppliers (what is printed upon the device):

- **Pi 2:** DC 5V, 1.2A
- **Pi 3 B+:** +5.1V, 2.5A

Can this 0.1 voltage difference generate some issue in the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nominal voltage for all Pi is the same i.e. 5V with 5% tolerance.

The PSU for later models is designed to provide slightly more to allow for the higher voltage drop in the cable (due to higher current).

They can quite safely be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think the voltage regulator should do fine with that 0.1 difference.

So, yes, I think that will do perfectly.